# String replaceAll() in java

Tags: java

Can you explain the output

```
String str = "Total Amount is AMOUNT";
String amount = "$10.00";
str = str.replaceAll("AMOUNT", amount);
System.out.println(str);
```

What is the output?
It throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
```

By removing $ its working.Why?

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: The answer is: use "\\$10.00" - but I don't know why ;-)

Comment: $ is a regex control character, so just like any other control character it must be escaped. Java being java, the escape has to be a double backslash.

Comment: Getting the same exception with JDK 1.7.0_45 here. Anyway, Codebender's explanation is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $ is special regex symbol. If you want to use it such usual symbol.

```java
String str = "Total Amount is AMOUNT";
String amount = "\\$10.00";
str = str.replaceAll("AMOUNT", amount);
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 12):

`String.replaceAll()` accepts a **regex**.

And `$` in regex are used for replacing the captured groups. Like `$1` represent's the content of first captured group... and so on.

In your case, since you don't use regex at all just use `String.replace("AMOUNT", amount)`

Comment: Alternatively: Escape the $ with "\\".

Comment: When you don't use regex, don't use a regex method. +1 for that.

Answer (score 4):

`$`is a special char in regex. 
You can escape it by using `\\`

```
      String amount = "\\$10.00";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write it as

```
String amount = "\\$10.00";
```

Answer (score -3):

When $ is provided it assumes it as regular expression, but actually its not.

Comment: The signature of replaceAll is `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) `

Comment: Its not regex currently, we need to escape the $ symbol.